# How to fix localtime structure corruption

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, malloc, localtime

I am trying to recover date and time in my C program. When I compile, it doesn't give error but when I run it, it gives me the following error : *** Error in `./owa4x_AN8': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00440068 ***.

Here is my code :

```
int h,min,s,day,mois,an;
time_t now;
time(&now);

printf("Aujourd'hui est : %s" , ctime(&now));


struct tm *local = localtime((&now));
h=local->tm_hour;
min= local-> tm_min;
s = local-> tm_sec;
day = local->tm_mday;
mois= local-> tm_mon +1;
an = local-> tm_year + 1900;



printf("L'heure : %d %d %d\n",h,min,s); 
printf("La date : %d %d %d \n",day,mois,an);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem this code would produce that error. Can you please provide the complete code? That is, code that anyone can compile **exactly** as shown and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `#include <time.h>` missing.

Comment: Check return value of `time()` before using `now` in `ctime()`.  At a minimum suggest  `time_t now;` --> `time_t now = 0;`.